# How to detect if the program stopped in any way

Tags: c, database, sqlite

So I have a this program in windows that relies on each other. And I have a loop that checks a certain condition and spawns GTime_mod.exe if the condition is true. As you can see in my code below it has an aux variable coming from a database, the variables default value is 1. Now if GTime_mod.exe is executed the and then when the user were able to give the right username and password, the value of aux will change to 0. Then when the user logout aux will change to 1 again. Now my problem is, I wan't the aux value to change to 1 again besides logging-out. Because there are cases when the `**[case 1]**` user will just press (X) button to close the program. Or the `**[case 2]**` user might stop the program by pressing `Ctrl + C`. And lastly `**[case 3]**` the user might close the program via task manager. Can anyone please help me or give me a suggestion on how to tackle this problem, your help will be highly appreciated.

```
int main(void){
    sqlite3 *db;
    time_t now;
    struct tm *local;
    int er;
    char *sqlCom;
    char *errMsg = 0;
    hr_mn high,low;
    int sdur = 0;
    int opt = 0;
    int cond = 0;
    int aux = 0;

    er = sqlite3_open("GTime.db",&db);
    if(er != SQLITE_OK) sqlite3_close(db),Err(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    er = sqlite3_exec(db,"SELECT * FROM TIMELIM WHERE ROWID = 1;",hrmn,&low,&errMsg);
    if(er != SQLITE_OK) sqlite3_close(db),Err(errMsg);
    er = sqlite3_exec(db,"SELECT * FROM TIMELIM WHERE ROWID = 2;",hrmn,&high,&errMsg);
    if(er != SQLITE_OK) sqlite3_close(db),Err(errMsg);
    er = sqlite3_exec(db,"SELECT * FROM TIMELIM WHERE ROWID = 3;",hrmn,&aux,&errMsg);
    if(er != SQLITE_OK) sqlite3_close(db),Err(errMsg);

    time(&now);
    local = localtime(&now);

    sdur = 30 - (local->tm_sec <= 30 ?  local->tm_sec : (local->tm_sec - 30));

    do{
        cond = (local->tm_hour >= low.hrs && local->tm_min < low.min) || 
        (local->tm_hour <= high.hrs && local->tm_min < high.min);
        if(!cond && aux){
            spawnl(P_WAIT,"C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown.exe","C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown.exe","/r /f /t 60 /c \" \"",NULL);
            opt = MessageBoxA( NULL, "System is shutting down", "GTime", MB_OKCANCEL|MB_ICONSTOP|MB_SYSTEMMODAL|MB_SETFOREGROUND|MB_TOPMOST );
            if(opt == 2){
                spawnl(P_WAIT,"GTime_mod.exe","GTime_mod.exe",NULL,NULL);
            }else
                exit(0);
            time(&now);
            local = localtime(&now);
            sleep(30 - (local->tm_sec <= 30 ?  local->tm_sec : (local->tm_sec - 30)));
        }else
            sleep(sdur);
        time(&now);
        local = localtime(&now);
        er = sqlite3_exec(db,"SELECT * FROM TIMELIM WHERE ROWID = 1;",hrmn,&low,&errMsg);
        if(er != SQLITE_OK) sqlite3_close(db),Err(errMsg);
        er = sqlite3_exec(db,"SELECT * FROM TIMELIM WHERE ROWID = 2;",hrmn,&high,&errMsg);
        if(er != SQLITE_OK) sqlite3_close(db),Err(errMsg);
        er = sqlite3_exec(db,"SELECT * FROM TIMELIM WHERE ROWID = 3;",hrmn,&aux,&errMsg);
        if(er != SQLITE_OK) sqlite3_close(db),Err(errMsg);
        sdur = 30;
    }while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

[Edit]
As for me case 1 is the highest priority to be solved as it is the most likely scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the [spawnl](https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/lib_ref/s/spawnl.html) documentaion you can get the exit value by using the `P_WAIT` flag.

So you just need to check that response value:

```
int exit_val;

[...]

exit_val = spawnl( P_WAIT, "GTime_mod.exe","GTime_mod.exe", NULL, NULL);
if ( exit_val == 1 ) 
{
  // manage exit
}
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I missed reading the return part of the function, tnx

Answer (score 1):

Move the code that changes the value back to 1 to a function, and register the function with `atexit` so it is always called when exiting the program.

Comment: Yeahh... tnx for this information. I did really find it useful later while building my project. As now it really comes in handy, I just found a case that I really needed this. tnx again